# how to get latitude and longitude from flickr photo Id in python?

Tags: python-3.x, flickr

I want to display the latitude and longitude of a flickr photo Id using python. I used the following code as

```
import flickrapi
import flickr

api_key = u'xxxxx'
secret_api_key = u'xxxxxx'

fr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, secret_api_key)
photoID=8636126004


for photo in flickr.photos.geo.getLocation(api_key=api_key,photo_id=photoID,extras="geo"):
    print (photo.attrib['id'])
    print (photo.attrib['latitude'])
    print (photo.attrib['longitude'])
```

But I get the following error as

> for photo in flickr.geo.getLocation(api_key=api_key,photo_id=photoID, 
>   extras="geo"):
>   AttributeError: module 'flickr' has no attribute 'photos'

Guide me to display the latitude and longitude of a flickr photo Id using python. Also guide me as

> What is the correct way to install flickr package in anaconda python 3.7. (Am I installed wrong flickr package?)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have more success with the [flickr.photos.geo.getLocation](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.geo.getLocation.html) endpoint.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestion. As per you suggestion I modified my question. Please go through my modified question once again and guide me to resolve the error. Thanks.